# buildSrc classes are not resolved in build.gradle scripts with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project.

I have `Hello.java` in `buildSrc/src/main/java/com/example` folder:

```java
package com.example;

public class Hello {
    public static void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

In the root `build.gradle` I have:

```
import com.example.Hello

task hello {
    doLast {
        Hello.printHello()
    }
}
```

Android Studio does not resolve the `Hello` class, but if I run `./gradlew hello`, "Hello" is printed out.

[image]

Gradle version: 5.2.1

Android Gradle plugin version: 3.3.2

Android Studio version 3.3.2

Comment: Looks like it is an Android Studio 3.3.x bug. I opened an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128350854